How to create a UI using streamlit and networkx to create graphs?
Hi I'd like to create a UI to manage the creation of a graph with streamlit and plotly.
I think one approach is to create buttons such as "add node", "delete node", "create edge" and create corresponding input fields for them etc but the big thing I'd like to achieve is some kind of point and click functionality so for example:

click a node and drag it to a new position
click 2 nodes to select where to create an edge
click a node and click delete

any guidance would be appreciated it

Streamlit only provides UI/UX functionality for components that are included in its documentation. As far as I know, any third-party Python modules can only be displayed as figures.
To create custom features from scratch, you must know JavaScript or TypeScript and add those features yourself.
However, my suggestion would be to use "Highcharts" in ReactJS or similar modules in other frameworks like Angular to achieve this.

have you tried this / have thoughts? seems to be promising but not sure https://github.com/null-jones/streamlit-plotly-events

Yes, I exactly meant this. Adding wrappers around streamlit with either typescript / javascript to make it interactive. This github can be used as a starting ground.
I have tried for one of my previous employer where I needed to created editable tables. At that time, streamlit didnt had this feature.
